# Compute engine- GCP Click to Deploy solution crashed

Tags: virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, certbot, google-deployment-manager, google-cloud-instances

I am using Google Cloud deployment manager -  Wordpress click to deploy solution.

I installed a certificate through the Virtual machine SSH on the compute engine page using [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=apache&os=debianbuster). Immediately after I installed the certificate the page started showing
"ssl_error_bad_cert_domain " and didn´t open.

I went back to the SSH and deleted the certificate by using the certbot command `$ sudo certbot delete` . Since that didn´t solved the error I tried turning off and on and also restarting the VM which didn't resolve the issue either

I could see in the logs explorer there was an error coming from the VM saying: `Invalid ssh key entry - expired key:[expired_key]` so I requested a new one through the VM ssh using:
`ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/gcloud_instance1 -C username`  printed the content of `cd ~/.ssh && cat gcloud_instance1.pub` and then added that to the VM ssh-keys text-area. That did stop the errors on the logs explorer but didn't solve the issue since the Wordpress implementation still doesn't open.

Another thing to add is that when the VM was turned off and on the IP address changed, which I am not sure it is also causing the crash.

This is how the page currently looks like: [webpage failing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5g7k.png)

This is the logs explorer : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cKXWkfaFbmUFakomwM_-TtoSelxWKBDxNBK7fnMy_PA/edit?usp=sharing

Any ideas what could be happening ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "ssl_error_bad_cert_domain" error can happen when the SSL certificate is not properly installed or is not issued for the correct domain.

My guess is that you had a typo in the domain name or you need a static ip.

You can use this "-sudo certbot certificates" command to verify after the installation.

It is recommended to have a static IP for better stability, especially if you are using SSL certificates.